# Tileserver-gl: Customization of Landing page and features with map for tileserver-gl on docker

Tags: openmaptiles, tileserver-gl, tileserver

This question may have already been answered somewhere, however, I can't find anything about it right away.

I am currently working on building/implementing webpage on a server that contains a map. The user should then be able to add markers to this map along with descriptions and some images attached to the marker (unsure how possible this is with tileserver-gl). I thought that tileserver-gl would work well for this. I have gone through and done all of the setup as recommended on the [GitHub page](https://github.com/maptiler/tileserver-gl). I am wondering if there is either a way to customize or to remove the initial landing page all together (pictured below). I mainly want to do this to allow for less user confusion (the users are not as experienced with tech).
[image: image of the landing page]

I am currently looking to see if manipulating aspects of the config.json (this is one of the many methods of operating with docker that they offer) file could help. **I am new to working with tileserver-gl so I apologize if this is should be a simple solution or if I am going about everything wrong. I tried to learn more but was not able to find much about this particular question.**

Answer (score 1):

First, you have to know that [Tileserver-gl](https://github.com/maptiler/tileserver-gl) is an

> An open-source map server made for vector tiles, and able to render into raster tiles with MapLibre GL Native engine on the server side. It provides maps to web and mobile applications

It's not a web application designed for customization or used as a UI for the application, the landing page - front page - you meant is just an easy way to show the available data, and styles on the map server.

You have to develop a simple web app using either [Mablibre-gl-js](https://github.com/maplibre/maplibre-gl-js) or [Mapbox-gl-js](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-js) libraries to do the required features (add a marker with a description and images) and using a map style from Tileserver-gl that you deployed as a base map - background - for your web app.

you can find some getting started examples for creating a simple web app using the MapLibre-gl-js library, from [link1](https://dev.to/olacampuspune/getting-started-with-maplibre-gl-js-gjl) and [link2](https://github.com/jawg/maplibre-gl-js-examples/blob/master/examples/add-marker.html).